# Unable to submit image generated form to a new webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webapp that generates a barcode:

```
protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string barCode = Barcode + txtCode.Text;
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 50, 90))
    {
       using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
       {
          Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 18);
          PointF point = new PointF(3f, 3f);
          SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
          SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
          graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
          graphics.DrawString(barCode, oFont, blackBrush, point);
       }
       using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
         bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
         byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

         Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
         imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
        }

           plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
}
```

It generates the barcodes on the same page, what I was hoping to do, is once the button is pressed it displays the results in a new webpage.

I created a session

```
Session.Add("BarCodes", plBarCode);
Response.Redirect("barcodes.aspx);
```

And then on the barcordes.aspx pages"

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  plbcode = (PlaceHolder)Session["Barcodes"];
}
```

That is incorrect since nothing shows up, but I don't know what else to try. I know I cannot use imgBarCode since it will be throw an exception of an Invalid Cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping WebControl in Session is not a good idea. Better way is to move barcode image generation code to second page and pass all necessary params via querystring:

`imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "barcodes.aspx?text=foobar&barcode=12345...";`

Second page generates an image and writes it directly to `Output` stream, with `image/png` content type, without any html markup. Only image data.

Comment: The user needs to input information that the generator takes to display the barcode, so I should take that information and then pass it to the new webform and have a method generate the barcode there?

Comment: It's strange that you need to display barcode on other page - why not use current page? But ok, it's you app. Ok, you can save string with "data:image/png;..." into Session.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it works perfectly when generated on the same page, but the barcodes need to be printed so I'm seeing if I can manipulate them more in the new page, although creating the session works fine now, but the generator is in a for loop printing multiple ones depending on user input, it just prints one on the new page. Thanks for getting me on the right path though.